# Pooled data in regression analysis

Tags: regression, pooling

I am performing my research on the most active 50 companies for a period of 5 years.  The most active 50 companies change every year.  I want to determine how my dependent variable is impacted by the explanatory variables without regarding the time and the companies.  So can I just pool all the data as one group and run my regression.

Comment: How are you defining "active?" What is your DV? Why would you not want to condition the estimates by structural factors such as time, sector and company?

Comment: The most 'active' is defined as the ones with highest trading activity.   My DV is levels of corporate disclosure.   And the independent variables consist of ownership structure variables as well as other firm characteristics.  I am not interested in how different time periods impacted my DV or how companies in different sectors behave differently with regards to disclosure.  All I am interested in is how different ownership structures impact the DV.  Since the most active companies differ each year, I just pooled them all together as one sample.  How strongly can I support this?

Comment: *Trading* as in stock market trading volume? "Disclosure" sounds like a judgmentally driven classification, is it? I understand that you only care about ownership but do you also understand the trade-off that entails? In other words, there may be factors moderating the bivariate relationship you care about that, if controlled for, would change aspects of this relationship. At a minimum, it should adjust the model parameters for any bias present if these factors are not used to condition the model estimates.

Answer (score 1):

Pooled OLS regressions in the case of Panel Data are usually frowned upon.First, if the conditional exogeneity condition holds, that is:
$$
E[(\alpha_{i}+u_{it}|X_{it})]=0
$$
 holds, then you might as well use a random effects estimator (In
the above expression, $\alpha_{i}$is the time invariant, individual
specific nuisance paramter and $u_{it}$ is the general error term)
Random Effects estimator is a GLS type estimator and is more efficient
that the pooled OLS estimator. In many cases, however , this condition
does not hold. As such, people invoke a Fixed Effects estimator that
effectively removes the nuisance paramter and uses within subject-over
time variation. You can actually 'test' the condition by conducting
a Hausmann test, which tests the weighted "squared'' difference
between the fixed effect and random effects estimators. If you reject
the null, you are better off using a fixed effects estimator. In any
case, it is weakly better to use a Randome effects estimator than
a pooled OLS one.

Comment: I would be interested in the reasons for your comment about PTS being "frowned upon."

Comment: Consistency/Unbiasedness of Pooled OLS requires strong assumptions about exogeneity. If (for some reason) one believes exogeneity holds (again extremely unlikely in panel data), it is better to use Random Effects. The choice should be between fixed effects and random effects. Pooled OLS is weakly worse than random effects.

Comment: Empirical papers based on panel data mostly use fixed effects or GMM type estimators in conjunction with pooled OLS

Comment: That is true about the strong assumptions. In my view, the flexibility of the pooled OLS framework outweighs some of these concerns. Not to mention that a move to FE or RE models can create as many problems as it is intended to solve.